# WebLogic JMS Cluster

Tags: weblogic, jms

I'm running Oracle WLS 10.3.5.0.

I have two Managed Servers and want to setup distributed JMS Queues on them.  However, I'm confused about the relationship between JMS Servers and Persistent Stores.

I have created two migratable JMS Servers, one on each Managed Server.  Each JMS Server points to its own Persistent Store on the same Managed Server, each with a unique prefix name.

So:

```
JMSServer1                    JMSServer2
PersistentStore1              PersistentStore2
Migratable ManagedServer 1    Migratable ManagedServer2
```

The WLS JMS Servers section shows:

```
JMSServer1  JDBCJmsStore1   ManagedServer_1 (migratable)    ManagedServer_1  OK
JMSServer2  JDBCJmsStore2   ManagedServer_2 (migratable)    ManagedServer_2  OK
```

Is that correct?

Many thanks.